# Ignoring new input until setTimeout() finished

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have a javascript function that when you mouse-over an image it changes that image's id to one that has a keyframe animation so it flys around for 10 seconds then comes back to where it started. At that point you should be able to mouse-over again and it flys the same way.

My question is how can I make it ignore any more mouse-overs while it is flying around? I have something like this right now:

```
<script>
  function fly(element){
    element.id="flynow";
    setTimeout( function(){stopflying(element)}, 10000 );
  }

  function stopflying(element){ 
    element.id="";
  }
</script>
```

Comment: How are the mouseovers triggered?

Comment: onmouseover="fly(this);"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote my own test functions for this, and while I didn't use the same method of output as you, the onmouseover events should be the same.

All I did was make a global variable for storing a boolean value. This tells if you are mid-flight or not. I am assuming that you only want 1 element to fly at a time, right?

My code:

```
var isFlying = false;
function fly(element){
    if(!flying){
        flying=true;
        element.id="flynow";
        setTimeout(function(){stopflying(element)} , 10000);
    }
}

function stopflying(){
    flying=false;
    element.id="";
}
```

This should work to only allow 1 element to fly at a time, regardless of how many times onmouseover would have been called.

Comment: I do want to have many elements flying at the same time, each with their own 10 second timer. I will try this code and see what I can do.

Comment: Hey I got it working thanks to your idea, all I did was change the line, "if(!flying){" to "if(element.id != "flynow"){". Then I removed the global variable since it wasn't needed any more.
Now it works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you do not adjust the timeout milliseconds also, it will appear to have ignored the timeout.

for example:

```
setTimeout("smoothscroll" , 1000)
setTimeout("smoothscroll" , 1000)
setTimeout("smoothscroll" , 1000)
setTimeout("smoothscroll" , 1000)
setTimeout("smoothscroll" , 1000)
```

will not fire the five functions 1 second apart but all of them at once, and within 1 second they will all respond simultaneously, appearing as if the timeout has been ignored.

```
setTimeout("smoothscroll" , 1000)
setTimeout("smoothscroll" , 2000)
setTimeout("smoothscroll" , 3000)
setTimeout("smoothscroll" , 4000)
setTimeout("smoothscroll" , 5000)
```

will fire them at once, but they will respond one second apart, which is the desired outcome.

Whether this phenomenon is created in a loop or as individual commands is irrelevant.

Hope this helps.

Nico